# No 16-jre-slim Docker image found

Tags: java, docker, adoptopenjdk

Does anybody know where can I find docker image JRE SLIM version for JAVA 16.
Couldn't find any from adoptopenjdk, openjdk nor amazoncorretto. Atleast it was not listed as "16-jre-slim" or smth similar.

Comment: I hear they changed the naming convention, but I cannot locate what the jre changed to. With 11 it was pretty easy: `openjdk:11-jre-slim`

Comment: See also [How to create an Alpine-based JRE-only Docker image of Amazon Corretto?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77343684/685806)

Answer (score 1):

Acording to [this commit](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-docker/commit/b0358ba92d4c84d2f32d1f25ac773de7169d54db) the combination of `slim` and `jre` was intentionally removed, because it's not supported:

> Remove slim jre combination from config files as that is not supported

I have no knowledge as to why this combination is no longer supported. That suggests that only `jdk` and `slim` can be combined.

Comment: are there any other 16:jre-slim variants left?