# How to create an Alpine-based JRE-only Docker image of Amazon Corretto?

Tags: java, docker, alpine-linux, jlink, corretto

I will deploy my dockerized Java application to AWS so I would like to use Amazon Corretto.  I also want to keep the size of the Docker image small so I want to use a JRE-only image based on Alpine.

Unfortunately Amazon does not provide a JRE-only image of Java 17 or Java 21 but I know I can create it using `jlink` so I tried this command

```
jlink --add-modules ALL-MODULE-PATH --output jre \
      --strip-debug --no-man-pages --no-header-files --compress=2
```

as suggested in [this page](https://adoptium.net/blog/2021/10/jlink-to-produce-own-runtime/).  It works on my Windows PC but on Alpine it gives a strange error:

```
Error: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "objcopy": error=2, No such file or directory
```

What does it mean?  How can I create the base image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Linux `jlink` needs a tool called `objcopy` that is not present in Alpine but can be installed with:

```
apk add --no-cache binutils
```

Also note that `--compress=2` is deprecated in Java 21 after [JDK-8293667](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8293667).  This fact is not reported yet in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/jlink.html#jlink-options) but is present in the help page that says:

```
--compress <compress>         Compression to use in compressing resources:
                              Accepted values are:
                              zip-[0-9], where zip-0 provides no compression,
                              and zip-9 provides the best compression.
                              Default is zip-6.
                              Deprecated values to be removed in a future release:
                              0:  No compression. Equivalent to zip-0.
                              1:  Constant String Sharing
                              2:  Equivalent to zip-6.
```

so in Java 21+ you should use `--compress=zip-6` or `--compress=zip-9`.

However I want to emphasize that an unofficial Alpine-based JRE-only image of Amazon Corretto already exists as [amazoncorretto-jre](https://hub.docker.com/r/pnavato/amazoncorretto-jre) so you could reduce your effort using it.  It is much smaller than other official JRE images and I use it in production.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to search for a ready-made image but the internal search engine of Docker Hub is not very effective: if you don't know the exact name of the image you get a lot of unuseful results.

Comment: Even if you don't want to use the unofficial image, it has a sample Dockerfile in the description that can help you build your own.